# Normalize names in a list (python)

Tags: python

I need to normalize names that are in a list. For example:
(brazilian names)

this: IGor DA  silva
should become this: Igor da Silva

-The first letter of every name should be capitalized, but only the first letter.
-The conecting words, such as "da" should be written in only lowercase
-All the extra spaces must be removed

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: What did you already try to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first letter of every name should be capitalized, but only the first letter.

Look into the string `.title()` method

> -The conecting words, such as "da" should be written in only lowercase

Look into the string `.lower()` method

> -All the extra spaces must be removed

Look into the string `.split()` method to separate the names and the `" ".join()` method to recombine them with a single space.

Comment: But how can these be used in strings that are in a list?

Comment: First, make a function that can fix a single name. Then loop over the list and apply that function to every name, and use the result to make a new list.